# angular-2(beta) view is not updating when retrieving data from Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase

The below code show that I am retrieving data from Firebase and at the same time I am updating my view using the binding syntax. The data is successfully retrieved and i have printed in my console but my view is updating very slowly. I had initialized my Firebase in the `index.html`.can anyone please explain me what is the problem actually, is there any thing wrong with initialization of firebase.

getting this error on the console **angular2-polyfills.js:493 Uncaught TypeError: fnRef.apply is not a function**

tahnks in advance

### `index.html`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
   <body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

### component

```
ngAfterContentInit() {

       this.singlehotel = {};
       firebase.database().ref('Rests/').once('value', function(snapshot) {
         console.log('value from db' + JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
         var getrest = snapshot.val();
         console.log(JSON.stringify(getrest));

           for (var key in getrest) {

                  if(restemail == getrest[key].email){

          console.log(key + ':' + JSON.stringify(getrest[key]));
                          this.singlehotel = getrest[key]; //getting error here when using this

         }         
            }
         });                
      }
```

### view

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
    <h1><b>Hotel Name :{{singlehotel.displayName}}</b></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the data you are expecting being displayed on the page or are you receiving an error as indicated by your code?

Comment: yes i want the data to be displayed on my page. i am getting no errors

Comment: as i mentioned i am retrieving data from db but my html is not updating as soon as the data arrived from the firebase. do you have any idea please help me @TeddySterne

Comment: Just simplify your life and use https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: i am using the beta version of angular-2, when npm the angularfire2 if finding ngmodule, i haven't used ngmodule in my application.so i ignored trying it.i am very new to angular-2 @Fabio Antunes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initialize your library outside Angular, then Angular doesn't recognize when change detection needs to be run.

As a workaround you can use `zone.run(...)`

Also with `function () ...` `this.` doesn't point to the current class instance. Use `() => ...` instead.
See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}

ngAfterContentInit() {
   this.singlehotel = {};
   firebase.database().ref('Rests/').once('value', (snapshot) => {
     this.zone.run(() => {
       console.log('value from db' + JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
       var getrest = snapshot.val();
       console.log(JSON.stringify(getrest));

       for (var key in getrest) {
         if(restemail == getrest[key].email){
           console.log(key + ':' + JSON.stringify(getrest[key]));
           this.singlehotel = getrest[key]; //getting error here when using this
         }         
       }
     });
   });                
 }
```

I'd suggest you use https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 instead.

Comment: Is ngzone need to import

Comment: Every type needs to be imported in TS. `import {NgZone} from '@angular/core'`

Comment: thanks @gunter Zochbauer... i tried it working as expected.

Comment: I have heard that there was another Angular before Angular2 but don't know anything about it